# Do smart contracts on NEAR have events?

Tags: nearprotocol

Do smart contracts have events now that I can set up listeners for or do I need to poll the chain manually to get data about them? (Rust)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NEAR Protocol doesn't have events, so you need to poll the chain manually or create an indexer to listen for everything in the network.

For the record, NEAR Protocol allows contract developers to use [Events Format](https://nomicon.io/Standards/EventsFormat) logs for a more standardized way of logging. That makes it easier to catch such logs via indexers.

[This indexer tutorial](https://near-indexers.io/tutorials/lake/nft-indexer) utilizes [NEAR Lake Framework JS](https://near-indexers.io/docs/projects/near-lake-framework) to catch Events Formatted logs.

Comment: `log!(
    r#"EVENT_JSON:{"standard": "nepXXX", "version": "1.0.0", "event": "YYY", "data": {"token_id": "{}"}}"#,
    token_id
);`                                                                                                                                                  Invalid format string